# Flutter TextField high CPU usage

Tags: flutter

With focus on a TextField / TextFormField with the cursor actively blinking, a huge amount of CPU time is used on any platform.

Apparently this is a [known issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/59327) and [still an issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/113192).

Is there a fix/workaround for this?

Answer (score 3):

Until this performance bug is addressed the easiest workaround is:

**don't animate the cursor fade**:

```
TextField(
  controller: ctrl,
  cursorOpacityAnimates: false, // ← this guy
```

Unfortunately `TextFormField` doesn't (yet) expose `cursorOpacityAnimates` as an argument so this is only available on `TextField`.

A future release of Flutter will include `cursorOpacityAnimates:` on `TextFormField` (it's already on `master` branch of Flutter).

[Thanks to Blquinn](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/122474) for exposing the arg to `TextField`.

Comment: It's extremely helpful that you mentioned TextFormField in this response. Thank you @Baker

Answer (score 0):

Very strange, on flutter web, when setting the TextFormField to cursorOpacityAnimates: true, the performance of my application improves by 3-4 times